# Incorrect result for a standing wave on a rope with free ends

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, waves, boundary-conditions, string

Given a rope with both ends free, the general solution is
$$\psi(x,t)=f(x-vt)+g(x+vt),$$
such that 
$$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(0,t)=0=\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(L,t).$$

### Question

If $f(x-vt)=\cos\left[k(x-vt)\right]$ then what is $g(x+vt)$ ?

The answer should be $g(x+vt)=\cos\left[k(x+vt)\right]$ but I am getting $g(x+vt)=-\cos\left[k(x+vt)\right]$.

### Attempted solution

From $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(0,t)=0$ we obtain
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(-vt)=-\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(vt),$$
which holds for all $t$. Thus
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(-u)=-\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(u),$$
which has a solution
$$g(u)=-f(-u).$$
Choose $u=x+vt$ and use $f(x+vt)=\cos\left[k(x+vt)\right]$ and the above equation yields
$$g(x+vt)=-\cos\left[k(x+vt)\right].$$

This is of course wrong because this gives 
$$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(0,t)=2\sin(\omega t)\neq 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

So to be a little bit more terse about it, you *almost* have the right equation, but remember that $f,g$ are functions of one variable only and therefore partial derivatives of these are totally meaningless. But we do have that  $$\left({\partial\psi\over\partial x}\right)_{t~\text{const},~x=0} = 0 ~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~f'(-\omega t) + g'(\omega t) = 0$$You are correct to replace the $\omega t$ with just a generic argument $u$, and to find that $$g'(u) = - f'(-u).$$
However your claim that this has the solution $g(u) = - f(-u)$ is *not correct*. This is because of the *chain rule* which says that the derivative of $p(x) = q(r(x))$ is not $p'(x) = q'(r(x))$ but is instead $$p'(x) = q'(r(x))\cdot r'(x).$$This means that the actual solution must be $g(u) = f(-u)$ so that the chain rule coming in this form of  $r(x) = -x, ~~r'(x) = -1$ introduces the minus sign that we see above.

Comment: Do all primes mean derivative with respect to the argument of the function? It seems that in the second line it means with respect to $x$ whereas in the third line with respect to the argument of the function.

Comment: @Diracology I am pretty sure that my use of primes is consistent all the way through and means $f'(x) = \lim_{\delta x\to 0} (f(x + \delta x) - f(x) )/\delta x,$ that is it is the intrinsic derivative of the function with no reference to what it is being called upon.

Answer (score 0):

So what was your error?

Your error is choosing $g(x,t) = -\cos (x+vt)$ which gives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \ne 0 $ at $x=0$

The choice of $g$ was flawed because you did not apply the condition $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 0 $  correctly.

So you wanted $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =  -\sin(x-vt) = -\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ at $x=0$.

which gives $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = - \sin (vt)$ and the function of $x+vt$ which satisfies this is $g(x,t) = +\cos (x+vt)$

---

The graphs below are snapshots at an instant of time $t$.

[image]

The function $f$ is a right travelling wave and is shown in red on the graph.

The function $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ is the gradient of the cosine function $f$ and is a sine function and with time it also travels to the right following the function $f$ (shown in mauve on the graph).

One of the conditions that you are imposing is that at $x=0$ you must have for all time $ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=0$

This means that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=0$ so the $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ graph must be the "opposite" of the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ graph and and so must be a sine graph travelling to the left as shown in blue.

Because you want that condition  $ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=0$ to hold for all times wave $g$ must be left travelling.

This means that the $g(x,t) = +\cos(x+vt)$.

If you picture in your mind a little later in time the $f$ and $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ graphs moving a little to the right with the $g$ and $\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}$ graphs moving a little to the left then you can image the intercepts on the y-axis of the gradient graphs both moving further from the origin by the same amount thus still having their sum euual to zero.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not sure that is correct. Wouldn't be $\psi(x,t)=2\sin x\sin vt\Rightarrow\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}=2\cos x\sin vt\Rightarrow\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(0,t)=2\sin vt$?

Comment: @user362271 In the light of your comment I have rewritten my answer.